# Best way to append object to a vector of smart pointers?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, smart-pointers

Considering the following classes:

```
class A {
 public:
    A() {};
 protected:
    int m1;
    float m2;
    // ...
}

class B {
 public:
    B() { };
    void add1(std::shared_ptr<A> _obj) { 
        data.push_back(_obj); 
    };
    void add2(A* _obj) { 
        data.push_back(_obj); 
    };
    void add3(A& _obj) { 
        data.push_back(&_obj); 
    };
 private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> data;
}
```

which of the methods `addX` in class `B` would be more suited/best practice for passing a new pointer into the vector? Considering that `data` is a vector of non-const smart pointers, I understand it is not possible to pass the object or the smart pointer by const reference without having to "de-const" them which is not advisable and considered bad practice. However, unless I am mistaken, all those methods end up instantiating a `shared_ptr` and then copying it into the vector? What are the differences between them?

Comment: All 3 have different meaning, and 3rd is actually wrong (I can't imagine any not dangerous use-case for it). You have to consider ownership of the objects when choosing the method. Which party should hold the ownership of the object? Caller of `add`? `B`? Both?

Comment: In this case, ownership is, by design, supposed to be shared, thus why I am using `shared_ptr`. Instances of `A` are however, are assumed to be instantiated  outside the scope of `B`, but after appended to the member vector, B can do whatever with it.

Comment: Option 2 is not using shared ownership. You expect caller to pass the ownership to `B`, because `B` will `delete` the pointer. And you need to make that very clear in documentation.

Comment: Note that you could also pass a `std::unique_ptr<A>` or a `std::weak_ptr<A>`. `add1` would accept either

Comment: @Caleth would there any advantages over a plain `shared_ptr`? Is `unique_ptr` for instance smaller and thus simpler to move?

Comment: It's advantageous when you already have one, e.g. because `class C` hands those out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to ensure that your API makes it clear that the callee is going to take ownership, the only viable method is `add1`. It makes it clear from the signature that whatever you give it is going to be retained by the callee.

You can improve it by using `std::move` and `.emplace_back`:

```
void add1(std::shared_ptr<A> _obj) 
{ 
    data.emplace_back(std::move(_obj)); 
}
```

`add2` is misleading, as a raw pointer might or might not imply ownership. Someone could pass a pointer to a stack-allocated variable.

`add3` has the same problem, but it is even more misleading as non-`const` references are commonly used for mutating an object in-place, not taking ownership of it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but don't modern compilers already avoid unnecessary copies in these type of simple functions? I was under the assumption that if smart_ptr object is created when calling `add1` (e.g. foo.add1(&bar) where bar is of type `A`), then push_back would already created the new entry in-place? Apparently that isn't so.

Comment: @joaocandre compilers get to elide copies when it isn't noticeable. `_obj` still exists for the rest of `add1`.

Comment: @joaocandre: no. There are only some very specific situations where copies are elided.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo just another small detail about this, why exactly is there an advantage in using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` here?

Answer (score 4):

`add2` is bad, because the function transfers ownership, and that shouldn't be done using bare pointers.

`add3` is even worse, because it is non-idiomatic in even pre-C++11 conventions, to transfer ownership of a pointer by passing a reference.

`add1` is good. It is clear from the function declaration who owns the resource (it is shared). However, you can avoid copying of the shared pointer:

```
void add1(std::shared_ptr<A> _obj) { 
    data.push_back(std::move(_obj)); 
};
```